# ggplot2 dot plot with two geom_segment lines per state

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I'm trying to make a dotplot with geom_segment() lines to show two different COVID infection rates: prison staffers and prison residents. I have observations for each state, and would like to produce two geom_segments and two geom_points per state. As you can see from the graph, I'm struggling with two different components:
1) I would like to have two segment lines per state (so two lines for Ohio, one for residents and one for staff, next to each other). Does anyone know how to do this? position_dodge only seems to move the geom_points and won't create two lines.
2) I would like to order the states by only prison resident infection counts. Currently, reorder(State,Count) is ordering them by the total sum of both resident and staff infections.

Here is the code I'm currently running (rdt=dataset, Count=infection count, State=observation grouping, Type=staff/resident infection count--data are stored long):

```
ggplot(rdt,aes(x=Count,y=reorder(State,Count),
               colour=Type))+
  geom_segment(aes(yend=State),xend=0,colour="grey50",
               position=position_dodge(width=2))+
  geom_point(size=3,aes(colour=Type),position=position_dodge(width=2))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())
```

[Current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4kIb.jpg)

Thank you for any help or insight you can provide.

Here is some sample `dput` output from my dataset for the first ten rows

```
    structure(list(State = structure(1:10, .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", 
"Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Federal", "Florida", "Georgia", 
"Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", 
"Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", 
"Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", 
"Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", 
"North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", 
"Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", 
"Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", 
"West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"), class = "factor"), 
    Date.R = structure(c(18403, 18403, 18403, 18403, 18403, 18403, 
    18403, 18403, 18403, 18403), class = "Date"), Type = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("General.Confirmed", 
    "Residents.Confirmed"), class = "factor"), Count = c(9, 4, 
    155, 1246, 959, 486, 689, 147, 187, 4724), Population = c(21154, 
    5143, 42282, 15593, 118431, 17621, 12218, 4053, 1790, 157340
    ), Ratio = c(0.000425451451262173, 0.000777756173439627, 
    0.00366586254198004, 0.0799076508689797, 0.00809754202869181, 
    0.0275807275410022, 0.0563922082173842, 0.0362694300518135, 
    0.104469273743017, 0.0300241515190034), Ratio100 = c(42.5451451262173, 
    77.7756173439627, 366.586254198004, 7990.76508689797, 809.754202869181, 
    2758.07275410022, 5639.22082173842, 3626.94300518135, 10446.9273743017, 
    3002.41515190034)), .Names = c("State", "Date.R", "Type", 
"Count", "Population", "Ratio", "Ratio100"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT: Here is the final code (changed the variables a bit, sorry):

```
rdt$Ratio <- rdt$Count/rdt$Population
rdt$Ratio100 <- rdt$Ratio*100000

rdt$State<- factor(rdt$State,unique(rdt$State)) #Starts graphing process
# switch general and residents around to order by other group
rdt$Type <- factor(rdt$Type,c("General.Confirmed","Residents.Confirmed"))

ggplot(rdt,aes(y=Ratio100,x=reorder(State,Ratio100),colour=Type))+
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin =0,ymax=Ratio100),
                  position=position_dodge(width=.7),size=2,fatten=1)+
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1",
                     name = "Unit of Observation", labels = c(
                       "US Population", "Prison Residents"))+
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) + 
  labs(title="COVID-19 Infection Rates for US General and Prison Population",
       caption="Data from UCLA COVID-19 Behind Bars Data Project",
       y="Infection Rate Per 100,000 People",
       x="State")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=dup_axis())+
  theme_bw()+
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar problem recently and after much experimenting I found that using geom_pointrange and coord_flip seemed to work for me.

```
rdt$State<- factor(rdt$State,unique(rdt$State))
# switch staff and residents around to order by other group
rdt$Type <- factor(rdt$Type,c("Staff.Confirmed","Residents.Confirmed"))

ggplot(rdt,aes(y=Count,x=reorder(State,Count),colour=Type))+
geom_point(size=3,position=position_dodge(width=0.2))+
geom_pointrange(aes(ymin =0,ymax=Count),position=position_dodge(width=0.2))+
scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) + 
coord_flip()
```

Comment: that worked great! Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it! Do you know if there is a way to use the `reorder` command in the `aes()` call to only order on `"Residents.Confirmed"`? When I try to run something like `x=reorder(State,Count[Type=="Residents.Confirmed"])` I get an error saying "arguments must have same length." I really appreciate both your help and @GregorThomas 's! You've made my day.

Comment: The answer above based on your data should plot by Resident.Confirmed, in line with your orginal graph in your question

Comment: Thanks for the help. For some reason, the ordering still isn't working (I think it's currently ordering by the sum of both Residents.Confirmed and Staff.Confirmed). Here's a link to what it looks like now (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EGkIc-wOrQKcrxZDt50Yafgt9rf5ENRx/view?usp=sharing). Any idea on how to fix it? I put the current code into the question at the very bottom. Thanks!

Comment: I should add that I changed the variables a bit, sorry. Ratio100 is what Count used to be, and I replaced Staff.Confirmed with General.Confirmed (which is the general US population). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Can you update the dput in the question as you've changed/added some new variables

Comment: thanks again for the help! I updated the dput in the question. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: @babybonobo the link you've posted(Google drive pdf a few comments aboce) the ouput looks to be ordered as you want - by prison residents, apart from the state Federal which looks like it has a missing value. If you add rdt<- rdt[!is.na(rdt$Ratio100),] before your plot that should sort it

Answer (score 0):

With all the same colors for the segments, `ggplot` isn't sure how you want them dodged. Add a `group` aesthetic to your mapping to tell it:

```
...
geom_segment(aes(yend = State, group = Type), xend = 0, colour = "grey50",
               position = position_dodge(width = 2)) +
...
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I implemented the suggested change and it was semi-successful. As you can see from the image link, the geom_segments still converge at the left side of the axis. Any way to not have that happen?
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_2-J9-KhBe4ufg80wH05NbybP50D0PJ6/view?usp=sharing)
`...
geom_segment(aes(yend=State,group=Type),xend=0,colour="grey50",
               position=position_dodge(width=2))
...`

Comment: You might need to switch your axes and use `coord_flip()`... not really sure. Maybe post a few lines of sample data? `dput(rdt[1:10, ])` would be really nice (or choose a more suitable sample than the first 10 rows)

Comment: Thanks for the help! dput is a bit of a mess, so I made a sample of code below. 

State: Alabama, Alabama, Arizona, Arizona
Count: 10, 5, 20, 50
Type: Staff.Confirmed, Residents.Confirmed, Staff.Confirmed, Residents.Confirmed

So the hope would be to have two geom_segments and two geom_points per state (one per type). The `group= fix` you suggested worked to get the geom_segments separated on the right side of the graph, but they still originate from the same point on the left side of the graph. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: in case you do want the `dput(rdt[1:7, ])` output, it's below:

structure(list(State = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
"California", "Colorado", "Connecticut"), Date.R = structure(c(18399, 
18399, 18399, 18399, 18399, 18399, 18399), class = "Date"), Type = c("Staff.Confirmed", 
"Staff.Confirmed", "Staff.Confirmed", "Staff.Confirmed", "Staff.Confirmed", 
"Staff.Confirmed", "Staff.Confirmed"), Count = c(29, 7, 64, 51, 
198, 29, 369)), .Names = c("State", "Date.R", "Type", "Count"
), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Please put it in your question, not down in the comment. And please use `dput` - it's valid R syntax anyone can copy/paste into their R session to get your data structure.

Comment: and I tried the coord_flip() idea but it just flipped the geom_segments so that they were vertical, rather than horizontal, which didn't solve the issue unfortunately. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Yes, the `coord_flip` approach would have you reverse your axes (switch all `x`s and `y`s) *and* do `coord_flip`, so the orientation will be preserved but `position_dodge` might do better.

Comment: sorry about that--I've put the output of `dput(droplevels(rdt[1:10, ]))` into the question. My apologies!

Comment: No worries! Thanks for being so responsive! I've got to get some work done now, but if no one else helps you first I'll try to take a look in a few hours.

Comment: thanks for the help so far! I ordered the `dput` output in the question so that there are observations for both types. I really appreciate your help!